# Using pure css animation to change positio statement on toggle class

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-animations, delay

I'm using a simple css animation and by clicking on a button I toggle class and playing animation reverse.
Unfortunately the animation play correctly on loading page but when i click on the button the animation don't run it give me the last keyframe without any animation and delay.

```
<div>
  <button>click</button>
  <span ></span>
</div>

span{display:block;width:100px;height:100px;}

@keyframes a{
from { background:red;}
to {background:lime;}
}


.opened{
  animation:a 1s;
  animation-direction:reverse;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-delay:3s;
}
span{
  animation:a 1s;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-delay:3s;
}

$("button").click(function(){
  $("span").toggleClass("opened");
});
```

Here is my code pen example [code pen](https://codepen.io/jean-chiementin/pen/RwExQKx)

Answer (score 0):

add jquery cdn and place your jquery code inside **$(document).ready();**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $("span").toggleClass("opened");
            });
        });
       
    </script>
```

if above is proper then you can modify css class like below:

```
.opened {
          animation:unset;
          /*animation: a 1s;
          animation-direction: reverse;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
          animation-delay: 3s;*/
      }
```

Comment: This not fix my issue, what I need is by clicking the button the background must animated from green to red, then by cliccking it a second time must animated from red to green but with a delay before start the animation. I can achieve it by adding a second animation but I wondering if there's a way to use the same animation and play it in reverse